# UML Activity Diagram question, in terms of displaying buttons?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Not sure if this is the correct way to represent the flow between the "Home" page button, "Culture" page button and the "Song" page button (as all these buttons are present in all of the pages, where the user is able to click any of these buttons and perform certain activities)

This seems very messy as the arrows are pointing in all direction, which is why I am stuck on how to represent this.

[image]

UI of the application:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you choose an activity diagram for this purpose? A state machine diagram is more appropriate. Clicking on a menu option transfers the application to a different state. You can use a superstate to model the transitions that can be made in any application state.

[image: state machine diagram]

I would use an activity diagram to visualize the paths through a complex use case, not all UI actions.

See [my paper 'Which UML models should we make'](https://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf), pages 12 and 13.

Comment: Nice and instructive article!